# How to render a component from a DB callback using Flux+React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm developing a Web Application using `React.js` (with `Material-UI`) following `Flux` architecture. In my project, I have two folders:  *app*, where `components`, `actions`, `stores`, `dispatcher` and `index.html` files are, and *server* folder, where there are `server.js` file, which listen for connections, and `database.js`, that handles db connection. I have defined a simple component, an `AppBar`, with a simple right icon. The state of this icon is: `{notify:false}`. In `database.js` file, I have created a simple call to `store` like this:

```
this.executeQuery = function(){
    this.connection.query('SELECT * FROM account', function(err, results) {
        if(err) throw err;
        NotificationsAction.newNotification();
    });
};
```

*NotificationsAction.js* contains the following code lines:

```
module.exports = {
    newNotification : function(){
        console.log("new notification in actions");
        Dispatcher.dispatch({
            actionType : 'NEW_NOTIFICATION'
        });
    }
};
```

Finally, *NotificationsIconStore.js* is:

```
Dispatcher.register(function(action) {
    console.log("action is "+action.actionType);
    switch (action.actionType){
        case 'NEW_NOTIFICATION':
            console.log("new notification in dispatcher");
            Store.newNotification();
            break;
    }
});

var Store = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    newNotification : function(){
        console.log("new notification in store");
        this.emit('change');
    },
    addChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.on("change", callback);
    },
    removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.removeListener("change", callback);
    }
});
```

Considering that AppBar component is registered to change event, why a simple call to DB through `executeQuery` function does not work?

Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you firing an ajax request to the server for accounts data?

Comment: @TusharArora thanks for reply. I think is what I'm doing. In server.js, the main file that runs the server, there's a `app.get("/query")` that call the first function of my post (executeQuery).

Comment: I think you should return the data to the client. Instead of using  NotificationsAction.newNotification(); you should somehow return the  data using response object to the client and let react handle that data.

Comment: Ok, maybe I cane be more clear. This server is "multipurpose". It contains a DB interface and a set of operations called by a mobile app. It also provides a backend admin panel (a web app). When mobile app call a function located for example in server.js, database is called. What I need is that DB makes his operations, and call an action to update a state in React web app. Is that possible? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function in your action file like this -

```
 receiveAccounts: function() {
    ApiUtils.getAccounts(function(result) {
      Dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: ActionTypes.RECEIVE_ACCOUNTS,
        accounts: result.accounts
      });
    });
  }
```

Now you need to create an ajax call to your backend api. You should create a separate file for that. Let's say you name it ApiUtils.js

```
function getAccounts(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/accounts',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
    success: callback,

    error: function(result) {
    }

  });
}
```

Now you need to return json data to the client. Be it an android app, admin application or user facing application. Our backend service will serve same data to every single client.

So your executeQuery method can be modified like this -

```
this.executeQuery = function(){
  this.connection.query('SELECT * FROM account', function(err, results) {
      if(err) {
        return res.json({'accounts': [], 'message': 'error' + error.toString()});
      } else {
        return res.json({'accounts': results, 'message': 'success'});
      }
  });
};
```

Now you need to extract data from action and save it in your store like this -

```
var _accounts = [];

function _setAccounts(accounts) {
  _accounts = accounts;
}

var Store = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
    newNotification : function(){
        console.log("new notification in store");
        this.emit('change');
    },
    getAll: function() {
      return _accounts;
    },
    addChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.on("change", callback);
    },
    removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
        this.removeListener("change", callback);
    }
});

Dispatcher.register(function(action) {
    console.log("action is "+action.actionType);
    switch (action.actionType){
        case 'RECEIVE_ACCOUNTS':
            _setAccounts(action.accounts);
            Store.newNotification();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks again. I tried your script and it does not work. What I'm trying to do is a sort of observer. When mobile app calls this.execute query, the script needs to change the state of notification icon. It's a sort of "reverse" flux? I don't know...Do you have any suggestions to my problem? Thank you again!

Comment: Yes it is possible. You just need to understand that as soon as db query is executed, a json response is sent to the react client which updates the store. As we have created an event listener on store data, the notification icon's state is going to change. You just need to write some code for notification icon to change its state as soon as data is received in the store.